# Why does this property change event fire when JFrame opens?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, propertychangelistener

I have a 2 [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)s that input the same information in different forms. I want to have one change when the user change the other. I have implemented something like this before using [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)s, however I have encountered a strange error this time.

When my [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) opens the [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) event is fired for no apparent reason. The value of [`getNewValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html#getNewValue%28%29) on the [`PropertyChangeEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) is null.

Here is all the code that references my label:

```
private JFormattedTextField fpsField;
```

Then later in my JFrame constructor:

```
fpsField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
fpsField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
        if(!updatingFPS){
            updatingFPS = true;

            Float fps = (Float) arg0.getNewValue();

            long newDelay = Math.round(1000/fps);
            delayField.setValue(newDelay);

            updatingFPS = false;
        }
    }
});
GridBagConstraints gbc_fpsField = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_fpsField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_fpsField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc_fpsField.gridx = 1;
gbc_fpsField.gridy = 0;
monitorPreferencesPane.add(fpsField, gbc_fpsField);
fpsField.setColumns(10);
```

As you can see I do not set the value in code and the event is called (and generates a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)) before I get a chance to type anything in. I have not written the listener for `delayField` yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the default value is `null`, the focus event fired when opening the `JFrame` will fire a property change event because `null` can not be adequately compared. See the full explanation with code below after the possible solutions.

One solution to get rid of the NPE is to set a default value to your `fpsField` before adding the `PropertyChangeListener` since doing that will not fire the `PropertyChange` event when the `JFrame` opens.

```
JFormattedTextField fpsField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
fpsField.setValue(0);
```

Another solution, if you can't set the default value, is to check if the old and new values in the event are actually different before updating your `delayField`. They are both `null` when the `JFrame` opens.

The reason the event is fired is because a `FocusEvent`, where the cause is `ACTIVATION` is fired and processed by your `JFormattedTextField`, which calls

```
    /**
 * Processes any focus events, such as
 * <code>FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED</code> or
 * <code>FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST</code>.
 *
 * @param e the <code>FocusEvent</code>
 * @see FocusEvent
 */
protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e) {
    super.processFocusEvent(e);

// ignore temporary focus event
if (e.isTemporary()) {
    return;
}

    if (isEdited() && e.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST) {
    InputContext ic = getInputContext();
    if (focusLostHandler == null) {
    focusLostHandler = new FocusLostHandler();
    }

    // if there is a composed text, process it first
    if ((ic != null) && composedTextExists) {
    ic.endComposition();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(focusLostHandler);
    } else {
    focusLostHandler.run();
    }
    }
    else if (!isEdited()) {
        // reformat
        setValue(getValue(), true, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
    /**
 * Does the setting of the value. If <code>createFormat</code> is true,
 * this will also obtain a new <code>AbstractFormatter</code> from the
 * current factory. The property change event will be fired if
 * <code>firePC</code> is true.
 */
private void setValue(Object value, boolean createFormat, boolean firePC) {
```

since `firePC` is `true`, it fires the `PropertyChange` event on `value`.

Finally, since the default value is `null`, the condition to actually fire the event

```
    /**
 * Support for reporting bound property changes for Object properties. 
 * This method can be called when a bound property has changed and it will
 * send the appropriate PropertyChangeEvent to any registered
 * PropertyChangeListeners.
 *
 * @param propertyName the property whose value has changed
 * @param oldValue the property's previous value
 * @param newValue the property's new value
 */
protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName,
                                  Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
    PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport;
    synchronized (getObjectLock()) {
        changeSupport = this.changeSupport;
    }
    if (changeSupport == null ||
        (oldValue != null && newValue != null && oldValue.equals(newValue))) {
        return;
    }
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
}
```

will fire it, `oldValue` and `newValue` being both `null`.

Comment: I think that documentation is about how the value set will be formatted into a `String` and not related to the actual value. Setting the value before the even would probably get around the exception, I could also simply check for a null value. I'm more asking this question not because I can't get around it, but because I don't understand what is happening and want to.

Comment: Found the whole chain of events finally.

Comment: I went to lunch and came back to an essay on the subject. Impressive work.